# Why my signed app only launch when executing through app "APK Installer" ? What can I do to fix it?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, installation, android-manifest, launcher

After I installed my app on device API 19. When I try to launch it "Application not installed" message shows.

When I run my app by using the "APK Installer" application - downloaded from Playstore, everything is great, but my app doesnt run by itself.

I configured Build Variant for release, have my app signed, read several forums and still dont know what to do. Please help!

**Gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'XXXXALIAS'
            keyPassword 'XXXPASS'
            storeFile file('XXXPATH')
            storePassword 'XXXXPASS'
    }
    llave {
        keyAlias 'XXXXXALIAS'
        keyPassword 'XXXXXPASS'
        storeFile file('XXXXPATH')
        storePassword 'XXXXPASS'
    }
}
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "apt.login"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    multiDexEnabled = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        debuggable false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.llave
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

**App gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**Manifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="apt.login"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="false"/>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="25" />

<permission android:name="apt.login.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="apt.login.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<application
    android:permission="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    android:testOnly="false"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    >

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX(MY API KEY)XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>

    <activity
        android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.Login"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">


    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



     <activity
        android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.CU1"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.CU2A"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.CU2B"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.CU2C"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.CU2D"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.CU2E"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.CU2F"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.CU2G"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.CU2H"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.CU2I"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.CU2J"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.CU5A"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.CU5B"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.CU5C"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".UIactivity.CU6"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".UIactivity.CU6Mapa"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".UIactivity.CU7"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".UIactivity.CU7Mapa"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".UIactivity.CU9Mapa"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".UIactivity.CU10A"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
<activity
    android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.CU10B"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".UIactivity.CU10C"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.CU11"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.CU12"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.CU14"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.CU15"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.CU16A"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.CU16B"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.CU16Mapa"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.CU17"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".UIactivity.CU17Mapa"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.CU17Prueba"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".UIactivity.CU21"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".UIactivity.CU21Mapa"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".UIactivity.CU22"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".UIactivity.CU23"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".UIactivity.CU23Mapa"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>

    <activity
    android:name=".UIactivity.CU24A"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".UIactivity.CU24B"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".UIactivity.CU24C"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".UIactivity.CU25A"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".UIactivity.CU25B"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>

    <activity
    android:name=".UIactivity.CU26"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".UIactivity.CU27A"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".UIactivity.CU27B"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".UIactivity.CU27C"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
<activity
    android:name=".UIactivity.CU28"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">

</activity>

<activity
        android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.MenuZonas"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>



    <activity
        android:name=".UIactivity.MenuUbicaciones"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".UIactivity.MenuPrestadores"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.AccesoVip"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.DetallesComercial"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.Splitbar"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.Menuadmin"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.MenuPrestador"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.Menuturist"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="apt.login.UIactivity.MonedasPaises"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

</application>
```

Comment: first you please uninstall the signed version from playstore and then try to install the release version

Comment: @stephingeorge Hi Stephen. I didn't upload my app to Playstore. The launcher app is what i got from Playstore.